# How to add additional keyword argument to all Django fields?

Tags: python, django, architecture

The application I am working on requires merging of identical type Django models. These models hold state that can be altered by chronological events, so it is not as straightforward as deep copying one object to the other, as it is not always correct to take the latest value or always copy truthy values for example.

I have written a model merging class to handle this operation, however, I need to be able to describe on a field by field basis whether it should be included in that merge and if it is to be included, how to handle that merge.

I have already tried creating a dictionary to describe this behaviour and pass it into the merger. However, this becomes unwieldy at greater levels of nesting and is very brittle to codebase change.

I have also tried adding a merge method to each individual model, which solved the problem but is highly susceptible to failure if a foreign key relationship that lives on a different model is missed, or the codebase changes.

I have started writing a custom version of every field in Django, as the fields feel like the correct place for the logic to live, but it also feels unwieldy and brittle to have to maintain custom versions of every field.

Is there a way in Django to add an additional keyword argument to the base Field class or perhaps decorate each field without having to subclass them?

Thanks

Comment: `__init__` method is implemented in `Field` class (Which is parent class of all `Field`). You want to add just `**kwargs` ?

Comment: @gachdavit I want to be able to add something like merge_mode=foo to each field e.g. models.CharField(blank=True, merge_mode=‘foo’). Ideally I would like to be able to access this when using get_fields later.

Comment: Why you do not like idea to Use inheritance ?

It's very safe.

Comment: @gachdavit I don’t mind using inheritance if I have to, it just felt a bit clumsy to me to have to subclass every field. But I suppose if it gets the job done...thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case this helps anybody else, I have ended up creating a mixin and subclassing each individual field. Below is a cut down example.

```
from django.db import models

class MappableFieldMixin():
    def __init__(self, should_map=True, map_mode=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.should_map = should_map
        if should_map and not map_mode:
            raise TypeError('Mappable field requires map_mode if should_map set to True')
        self.map_mode = map_mode
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        kwargs['should_map'] = self.should_map
        kwargs['map_mode'] = self.map_mode
        return name, path, args, kwargs

class MappableBooleanField(MappableFieldMixin, models.BooleanField):
    pass
```

Usage:

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    is_active = MappableBooleanField(map_mode=MapMode.MAP_ALWAYS, default=True)
```

You can find further information on creating custom fields in the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-model-fields/).